# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression with Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't why it's working all browser except safari
here is my code:

```
if($(".instructor-container[data-message-id='" + result[i].Message.id + "']").length==0){
   //.....
   }
```

when I try to console log the

```
".instructor-container[data-message-id='" + result[i].Message.id + "']"
```

it show something like this :

```
.instructor-container[data-message-id='98']
```

but the error was something like this:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .seen-or-not[data-message-id='1'
```

Comment: If that's your error, I believe the issue is on a different line than the lines you've shared.

Comment: @mevius you're right , thk